# The name 'Classes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a user control that produces a list of hyperlinks on my page. the problem is that it does not seem to want to work. this is my code for the usercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="DepartmentsList.ascx.cs"
Inherits="BaloonShop.UserControls.DepartmentsList" %>
<asp:DataList ID="list" runat="server" CssClass="departmentslist" Width="200px">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="departmentslisthead" />
<HeaderTemplate>
    Choose a Department
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Classes.Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'
    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()) %>'
    ToolTip='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Description").ToString()) %>'
    CssClass='<%# Eval("DepartmentID").ToString() == Request.Querystring["DepartmentID"] ? "departmentselected" : "departmentunselected" %>'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The structure of my files are as follows:

[image: File Structure]

Why is it saying it cant find the Classes folder?

If you need any-more information please ask.

**EDIT**

Code for link class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BaloonShop.Classes
{
/// <summary>
/// Link factory class
/// </summary>
public class Link
{
    // Builds an absolute URL
    private static string BuildAbsolute(string relativeUri)
    {
        // get current uri
        Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        // build absolute path
        string app = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        if (!app.EndsWith("/")) app += "/";
        relativeUri = relativeUri.TrimStart('/');
        // return the absolute path
        return HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(String.Format("http://{0}:{1}{2}{3}", uri.Host, uri.Port, app, relativeUri));
    }

    // Generate a department URL
    public static string ToDepartment(string departmentId, string page)
    {
        if (page == "1")
            return BuildAbsolute(String.Format("Catalog.aspx?DepartmentID={0}", departmentId));
        else
            return BuildAbsolute(String.Format("Catalog.aspx?DepartmentId={0}&Page={1}", departmentId, page));
    }

    // Generate a department URL for the first page
    public static string ToDepartment(string departmentId)
    {
        return ToDepartment(departmentId, "1");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can we see the code for your `Link` class?

Comment: try to separatly include each class in the folder

Comment: Do you mean move every class into the main structure of the project?

Comment: nope..i mean it can happen that poster has not incuded the folder or class file in the folder properly...thats why error is comming...

Comment: can you show code block of your usercontrol

Comment: @dpk_0702 The code for my usercontrol is in my main post

Comment: @glenn robson how did you called link.cs in your usercontrol??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public link link= new link();` in DepartmentsList.ascx.cs"  will solve your problem.
use this:
`NavigateUrl='<%# Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'`

Comment: you have not created instance of the link class so it is giving you an error,`public partial class Bills :             System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ***here****
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {`

Comment: if `link link= new link();` does not helped use `public link link= new link();` instead

Comment: The error im getting is : CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Querystring' and no extension method 'Querystring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try the above one using public

Comment: are you still using `NavigateUrl='<%# BaloonShop.Classes.Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'` ?

Comment: try with this `NavigateUrl='<%# link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'`

Comment: it just goes back to CS0103: The name 'Link' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ok thats fine when you made instance of your class **Link** what name you have given is the name you should put in your navigate url.

Comment: That sentence has me confused.

Comment: the name of your class is Link.cs right, when i asked you to add this line `public link lnk = new link();` you created an instance of your class the second word lnk is the one you should put in your url. now your url `NavigateUrl='<%# lnk.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'`

Comment: Yes I get that but since i am getting the new error about querystring surely it is finding the class file?

Comment: I fixed it. My problem was in the line:

'CssClass='<%# Eval("DepartmentID").ToString() == Request.Querystring["DepartmentID"] ? "departmentselected" : "departmentunselected" %>'>'

Querystring needed to be Query **S** tring

Answer (score 0):

Your code just refers to `Classes`. Unless you are already importing `BaloonShop`, then this only refers to `global::Classes`, but your namespace is `global::BaloonShop.Classes`.

So: use `BaloonShop.Classes` instead of `Classes`:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# BaloonShop.Classes.Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%>'
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of that error message but now im getting a new one: 

CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Querystring' and no extension method 'Querystring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project (in visual studio) and choose Add ASP.NET folder and then choose **App_Code**.
Next Drag Your classes folder to to **App_Code**.
It might then resolve the issue

Comment: there is no option for App_Code. The only options are App_GlobalResources, App_LocalResources, App_Browsers, Theme and App_Data (but App_Data is not selectable).

Comment: you need to add that explicitly

Comment: right click on ur project and choos New Folder and then rename that folder to Add_Code

Comment: As in right click add folder and then just type the name App_Code?

Comment: you can rename the folder by single clicking on 'New Folder' (and remember to backup before u do this)

Comment: The same error: The name 'Link' does not exist in the current context

Comment: did u get error here NavigateUrl='<%# Classes.Link.ToDepartment(Eval("DepartmentID").ToString())%

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17055/discussion-between-dotnet-dreamer-and-glen-robson)